# Unescape / Decode an string in python

Tags: python, escaping, decode

I am making an AJAX request which returns JSON, but the JSON is a splurge of escaped HTML, is there any way I can unescape it using python nicely, (I don't want to use search and replace)

I have tried

```
 >>> print this.decode('string_escape')
```

that nearly worked but it didnt unescape thing like "\/"

```
\n\n\n\n    <div id=\"artikel_127997\" class=\"itemPrev product-box-wrapper 
la3r1 la4r1    
la5r1 la3c1 la4c1 la5c1\" itemscope itemtype=\"http:\/\/schema.org\/Product\">\n
                           \n<div class=\"product-box\"><div class=\"title-and-
 description\"><h3 class=\"title\"><a href=\"\/en\/buy\/bianchi-kuma-26.5-127997\/wg_id-
6666\" title=\"Bianchi Kuma 26.5\" itemprop=\"url\"><span class=\"manufacturer 
manufacturer-black\" itemprop=\"brand\">Bianchi<\/span><span>Kuma 26.5<\/span><\/a>
<\/h3>
<meta itemprop=\"name\" content=\"Bianchi Kuma 26.5\"><div class=\"description\" 
itemprop=\"description\">
```

the out put of this was

```
<div class="product-box"><div class="title-and-description"><h3 class="title"><a
href="\/en\/buy\/bianchi-kuma-26.5-127997\/wg_id-6666" title="Bianchi Kuma 26.5" 
itemprop="url"><span class="manufacturer manufacturer-black" 
 itemprop="brand">Bianchi<\/span><span>Kuma 26.5<\/span><\/a><\/h3><meta itemprop="name" 
content="Bianchi Kuma 26.5"><div class="description" itemprop="description">
```

I could just search and replace all the "\/"s but isn't there a better way?

Comment: You probably need to manually `.replace(r'\/', '/')`, since escaping `/` isn't really something that makes any sense. I don't suppose you can just get whatever is generating that "JSON"  to send actual JSON instead of whatever it's sending now?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I did in the end, was hoping this would be built in because i'm wondering if the decode method is missing this, then what else will it be missing in the future, I think getting the PHP file to pump out json without the escaped characters won't be possible in this case, but it is something I could look into

Comment: Well, the string-escape codec only escapes and unescapes strings correctly. It will be "missing" the ability to unescape stuff that never should have been escaped in the first place.